Why does my iPhone 16 Pro have iOS 18.0 but I can’t find a way to activate developer mode anywhere?
I just upgraded to an iPhone 16 Pro and it has iOS 18.0.
I don't see the developer mode option anywhere! I've seen some people saying I have to fully reset my iPhone, and others saying I need to download some apps. I don't want to do the former, and the latter seems shady.
Am I missing something?
Isn't there a straight forward way of activating developer mode on iOS 18?

Here’s what I have found:

My iPhone was on “Low Battery Mode.”
I connected it to my Mac and opened “XCode > Window > Devices & Simulators.”
Select “Allow” on my mac
Select “Trust” on my iPhone
Now “Developer Mode” is showing in “Privacy & Security.”

